# What transformer can I use to put a date into YYYY - MM - DD format with no time format in final result?

Tags: webmethods

I just started using webMETHODS today and need to transform a date input value that comes in like this.

Example:

yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:hh

I need just the date portion of this variable and am currently using pub.date:formatDate which will crash my flow service.

What should I be using?

[image: This is what I see on my WEBMethods screen!]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pub.date:formatDate` is used to convert a date input to a string output based on a string pattern. 
Here you are trying to convert a string input to a string output.

You have to do the following:
a. 
First convert the string (Process_date_orig_str) to date format (Process_date_dt)
b. Then use the date (Process_date_dt) to the required string format using `pub.date:formatDate` to get (Process_date_new_str)

*Note: You will have to create your custom java service to convert string to Date.*

Answer (score 5):

An alternative would be to use `pub.date:dateTimeFormat`, which allows you to set an input pattern, for example `dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this for practise. The 'correct' answer is what Christian Strempfer posted - this is what pub.date:dateTimeFormat is meant to do: transform beween datetime string formats. I'm not sure about your date pattern though - try currentPattern=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS and newPattern=yyyy-MM-dd

A 'good hacky approach is using pub.string:subString (positions 0 and 10) to simply hack the end off the input string. You can also try regexs -- pub.string:replace, useRegex=true, searchString=^(.{10}).*, replaceString=$1. (searchString=^(.{10}) should also work, but it doesn't)

Comment: if you use `searchString=^(.{10})` and `replaceString=$1` you are just asking to find a group (anchored at the beginning of the string) and replacing it with itself. The correct `searchString=^(.{10}).*` means you are searching for the full string, with a group pattern, AND replacing the entire string for the group.